# Library for mathematical calculations 

Tags: android, math, calculator

I am working on simple calculator & I want an library file which will do the calculations for me.

```
I tried using arity2.0.1 but it gives wrong answers.
```

Does anyone know about this?

Thank You.

Comment: I found the solution.. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [java.lang.Math](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)?

Comment: 5*9+(sqrt 10)^3

for these kind of calculations I need to right own logic to split & other stuff...

Answer (score 0):

What functions do you need in an external library for a 'simple' calculator?

Edit:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: I want to do +,*,-,/,^,log,sin,cos,tan,pi,1/x,sqrt,(,)

Comment: The standard java.Math library is adequate for your needs: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: How to do calculations included in brackets like
453*(sin(60)*452)/45

Comment: Take a look at this implementation: http://www.geoffknagge.com/java/calc/Calculator.java Bare in mind that there are many ways to approach this, and it's up to you to find the way that you find easiest :)